# Get Youtube Earnings from content owner report?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

1. Without using youtube CMS account can I get the Earnings of logged in User. If hes please tell how to do that using python. I am having CMS account also.
       I have added the scope 
       https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly to get content report as mention in [documentation](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/batch_report_download.py).

   ```
       from datetime import datetime, timedelta
       import httplib2
       import os
       import sys

       from apiclient.discovery import build
       from apiclient.errors import HttpError
       from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
       from oauth2client.file import Storage
       from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

       CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

       YOUTUBE_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly"]
       YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
       YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
       YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtubeAnalytics"
       YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_VERSION = "v1"
       MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = "credentials missed"

       def get_authenticated_services(args):
         flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
           scope=" ".join(YOUTUBE_SCOPES),
           message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

         storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
         credentials = storage.get()

         if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
           credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

         http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

         youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
           http=http)
         youtube_analytics = build(YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_SERVICE_NAME,
           YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_VERSION, http=http)

         return (youtube, youtube_analytics)


       def get_channel_id(youtube):
         channels_list_response = youtube.channels().list(
           mine=True,
           part="id"
         ).execute()

         return channels_list_response["items"][0]["id"]

       def run_analytics_report(youtube_analytics, channel_id, options):
         print channel_id, options.metrics, options.end_date, '2015-03-28'
         # Call the Analytics API to retrieve a report. For a list of available
         # reports, see:
         # https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports
         analytics_query_response = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
           ids="channel==%s" % channel_id,
           metrics=options.metrics,
           dimensions=options.dimensions,
           start_date='2014-03-28',
           end_date='2015-03-28',
           max_results=options.max_results,
           sort=options.sort
         ).execute()

         print "Analytics Data for Channel %s" % channel_id
         print analytics_query_response
         for column_header in analytics_query_response.get("columnHeaders", []):
           print "%-20s" % column_header["name"],

         for row in analytics_query_response.get("rows", []):
           for value in row:
             print "%-20s" % value,


       if __name__ == "__main__":
         now = datetime.now()
         one_day_ago = (now - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
         one_week_ago = (now - timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

         argparser.add_argument("--metrics", help="Report metrics",
           default="views,earnings")
         argparser.add_argument("--dimensions", help="Report dimensions",
           default="video")
         argparser.add_argument("--start-date", default=one_week_ago,
           help="Start date, in YYYY-MM-DD format")
         argparser.add_argument("--end-date", default=one_day_ago,
           help="End date, in YYYY-MM-DD format")
         argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=10)
         argparser.add_argument("--sort", help="Sort order", default="-views")
         args = argparser.parse_args()

         (youtube, youtube_analytics) = get_authenticated_services(args)
         try:
           channel_id = get_channel_id(youtube)
           run_analytics_report(youtube_analytics, channel_id, args)
         except HttpError, e:
           print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
   ```

I have used the above code I got the below error.

```
        raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
    oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

If i login with other accounts I got an error called.

```
An HTTP error 401 occurred:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "unauthorized",
    "message": "Insufficient permission to access this report."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Insufficient permission to access this report."
 }
}
```

If I run the above code except the 'earnings' in metrics I can get the exact output as I need.

Please tell how to get earnings in that by using python.

I have used [this](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/batch_report_download.py) also but it shows an error called `error: argument --content-owner-id is required`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: are you still looking for an answer here?

Comment: yes, I didn't get any proper response

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you need a YouTube CMS account and access to the YouTube Content ID API in order to retrieve earnings metrics for a logged in user.

You can see more discussion about this here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4826

Comment: I have a CMS account and I already enable the Youtube Content ID API. But I can't able to get the earnings report as well

Comment: Try adding this scope aswell.
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-content-owner-readonly`